How do I use SUMIFS/XLOOKUP to count each sale?
Using Google Sheets, I'm trying to count individual sales for each SKU. Some of the SKU's are bundles of certain amounts, and I don't know how to get the amount of items in said bundle.

For example, at O14, I sold one pack, containing 10 units of that particular SKU. I tried using SUMIFS and XLOOKUP, but when looking for that particular SKU, I need to know that 10 units were sold.

I suggest you make another column, extract the value like so:
=IF(REGEXMATCH(O8, "\d+\*.*"),LEFT(O8,FIND("*",O8)-1),1)

This will get you the value before the *, or 1 if not present. Then you can multiply it with the first column.

@PanchitaFTW If this answer helped you solve your problem, please accept it (by clicking the checkmark next to it), and upvote it once you have enough reputation. Also, do not ask additional questions in the comments, create a new question instead. Please retake the [tour] to better understand what Stack Overflow is and how to use it.
